# Map a one to many reference in Entity Framework as collection of ids instead of actual entity reference

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-nhibernate, one-to-many

In Fluent Nhibernate I can map a multiple entity references 1-M as a list of int ids :

```
    public class User{
     List<int> LicensesIds{
      get;
      set;
    }
```

Instead of

```
Public class User{
 ICollectoin<License> Licenses{
  get;
  set;
 }
}
```

Which is how Entity Framework maps it.
In the fluent mapping when I query the DB I get it with a list of ids instead of a list of entities.

Is there away I can map this the same way in Entity Framework ?

The reason I need it is because I am using the Repository pattern and have created a repository for each entity in the domain : Repository and I do not want to define what relations to query and get with an entity when I query the DB by using LINQ or by lazy binding in the middle of a property call without me being aware that this property call is now going to fetch data from the DB.
I want to bring the entities manually by querying the relevant repository.

Thx ,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You must always have list of licences in your entity if you want EF to handle loading for you (you can than expose second property doing just projection to list of integers). If you want just list of int implement custom logic in your repository which will execute additional query and fill it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a service that solves this problem for entity framework:

First we do a setup:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // Other common properties...
}


public class Book : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}


public class Person : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; private set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

We need repositories:

```
public interface ICrudRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);
    Task<List<T>> GetToListAsync();
    Task CreateAsync(T entity);
    // Additional CRUD operations as needed...
}

public class BookRepository : ICrudRepository<Person>
{
    // The base class already provides the necessary CRUD operations.
    // Additional specific methods for Person can be added here if needed.
}

public class PersonRepository : ICrudRepository<Person>
{
    // The base class already provides the necessary CRUD operations.
    // Additional specific methods for Person can be added here if needed.
}

public class CrudRepository<T> : ICrudRepository<T> where T :  BaseEntity, new()
{
    private readonly List<T> _entities = new List<T>();

public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
{
    // Simulates asynchronous operation
    return await Task.FromResult(_entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id));
}

    public async Task<List<T>> GetToListAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous operation
        return await Task.FromResult(_entities.ToList());
    }

    public async Task CreateAsync(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Add(entity);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Implement other CRUD methods as necessary...
}
```

Then we have a generic method that updates the collection based on ids:

```
public class CollectionUpdaterService
{
    public async Task ReplaceCollectionItems<TEntity, TSubEntity>(
        ICrudRepository<TSubEntity> repository,
        List<Guid> ids,
        TEntity entity,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TSubEntity>>> collectionPropertySelector)
        where TEntity : BaseEntity
        where TSubEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (!ids.Any()) return;

        var subEntities = await repository.GetFilteredToListAsync(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));

        // Compile and invoke the selector
        var collectionProperty = collectionPropertySelector.Compile().Invoke(entity);

        // If the collection is null, initialize it
        if (collectionProperty == null)
        {
            collectionProperty = new List<TSubEntity>();
            var propertyInfo = (collectionPropertySelector.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo;
            propertyInfo?.SetValue(entity, collectionProperty);
        }

        collectionProperty.Clear();
        foreach (var subEntity in subEntities)
        {
            collectionProperty.Add(subEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    var bookIds = new List<int>{1,2,3};

    var person = _personRepository.GetById(1);

    await _collectionUpdaterService.ReplaceCollectionItems( _bookRepository, bookIds , person, person => person.Books);
```